# Modular forms on $\Gamma(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

I'm wondering where I can find a good reference about what is known about modular forms (especially cuspidal eigenforms) of full principal level $\Gamma(N)$, in terms of their Hecke theory, old/newform theory, rationality properties, action of automorphisms from $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$, functional equations, etc. Everywhere I look writers seem to address mostly only the nice multiplicity one cases of $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$.

If possible, I'd like it in classical language, though automorphic language is fine too.

Comment: I don't think this kind of thing is written down anywhere. The key point is that
$$\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma(N)) = \bigoplus_{\chi \pmod{N}} \mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma_0(N^2),\chi).$$
More precisely, given $f \in \mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma_0(N^2),\chi)$, the function $g(z) = f(z/q)$ is an element of $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma(N))$, and every element arises in this way (up to taking appropriate linear combinations). So all of the key properties of $\Gamma(N)$ can be reduced to properties for $\Gamma_0(N)$ and $\Gamma_1(N)$.

Comment: If you adopt the automorphic language, then by Casselman's theorem, for any irreducible smooth representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, the new vector will be on $\Gamma_1(p^r)$ for some $r$. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2796

Comment: In his PhD thesis, Weinstein has computed the decomposition of $S_k(\Gamma(N))$ as a $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$-module. https://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/jswthesis.pdf

Comment: Also see LMFDB https://www.lmfdb.org

Comment: Did you try Cohen-Stromberg or Miyake?  Those are fairly thorough treatments of modular forms, and they probably at least explain Peter's comment.  (Diamond-Shurman probably explains Peter's comment as well.)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault thanks, that's very helpful!

Comment: @PeterHumphries I managed to find it in Miyake, I guess you meant z/N and not z/q, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.